# python pandas.column index number to real column name

Tags: python, pandas

I'm trying to deal with data that is xls written in html(or xml. IDK)
I tried to do this

```
df = pandas.read_html(r"filename.xls", skiprows=0)
```

and it was not dataframe but just list. so I did this

```
df = df[0]
```

and after this, I could do,

```
print(df)
```

the result is as below

```
    0   1   2
0   name    age gender
1   john    18  male
2   ryan    20  male
```

before, I did similar task with other xlsx files that just worked fine but not with this one.

for instance,

```
for index, row in df.itterrows():
     target = str(row['gender'])
     if target = 'male':
          df.loc[index,'gender'] = 'Y'
     else:
          df.loc[index,'gender'] = 'N'
```

in real, the code is 400 lines long....

I want my dataframe looks like below so that I can re-use the code that I wrote already.

```
    name    age gender
0   john    18  male
1   ryan    20  male
```

as the comment, I'm adding this result too.
I tried to skip the row

```
df = pandas.read_html(r"filename.xls", skiprows=1)
```

the result is as below

```
    0   1   2
0   john    18  male
1   ryan    20  male
```

how would I do it?

Comment: Try `skiprows=1` instead?

Comment: If you need a fix, you can slice and assign: `c = df.iloc[0]; df = df.iloc[1:]; df.columns = c`. although I think this is a dupe.

Answer (score 2):

Use parameter `header=0`:

```
df = pandas.read_html(r"filename.xls", header=0)[0]
```

And then instead loops is posible use `np.where`:

change:

```
for index, row in df.itterrows():
     target = str(row['gender'])
     if target = 'male':
          df.loc[index,'gender'] = 'Y'
     else:
          df.loc[index,'gender'] = 'N'
```

to:

```
df['gender'] = np.where(df['gender'] == 'male', 'Y', 'N')
```

Comment: oh!!!! instead of header=1, header=0 works!!!!! Thank you so much @jezrael